# unable to get an input of a string

Tags: c++, string, input, user-input

I am trying to make a program to try out all the functions of a C-string.

I have taken two inputs, the 1st input is taken, but the 2nd input is not taking. How can I correct my program?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[100];
    char bstring[50]="how are you\n";
    char c[100];
     
    cout<<"input string 1\n";
    cin.get(a,100);
     
    cout<<"input string 2\n";
    cin.get(bstring,50);
          
    strcpy(c,a);
    cout<<" after cpy a into c \n"<<c;
         
    strcat(a,bstring);
    cout<<"  after cat b into a  \n"<<a;
         
    cout<<"length of a  \n"<<sizeof(a);
         
    if(strcmp(a,bstring)== -1){
        cout<<"str1 is smaller \n";
    }else if(strcmp(a,bstring)==0){
        cout<<"both are equal \n";
    }else if(strcmp(a,bstring)== 1){
        cout<<"str1 is grater \n";
    }
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Please use an IDE which can format your code. The indentation is horrible.

Comment: Notes: `sizeof(a);` returns the sizeof the array, not the length of the string. Use `strlen()` for that. Also, I don't think there is any guarantee that `strcmp` will return `-1` or `1`. Just `< 0` or `> 0`.

Comment: Why are you using C-strings in C++ at all? If you use `std::string` instead, then this whole code can be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 1):

You need another `cin.get();` after reading a C-string with `cin.get()`. This will consume the end-of-line character. Otherwise, that end-of-line will be the next string. Or, use `cin.getline()` to read the string and consume the end-of-line in one go.

Note that `sizeof(a)` will always be 100, no matter how long the string is. Also, as mentioned in the comments, [`strcmp()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) should be compared `<0` and `>0`.